# Syncing files in a branch on dev server

Tags: git

I have created a branch called 'dan-development' off the master branch.  We're using github, and the github app on our desktops.  I commited then synced everything, and now want to show those updates on my development server (command line).

I've switched the branch to dan-development on the dev server, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab updates or sync it.

I've tried git pull, git fetch.  Neither seem to do anything.

Help?

Comment: did you check, if dan-development actually got pushed to the github repo?

Comment: Yes, its there, and when I go to another client and sync with the github app, it shows.  Is pull or fetch the right way to approach this?  Or am I on the wrong commands?

Comment: Basically you use the right commands! To fetch, I use `git fetch origin` (origin is the standard remote) and this normally fetches **all** the branches... Sorry can't help you for this

Comment: Ok cool.  Thanks for the confirmation on the commands.  that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dan Joseph, from command line you can do one thing "git reset --hard HEAD^", this cleans your history, now you can simply "git pull origin branchname", you should get all the updated changes.